# Why do I have to turn on wifi by commands every time Ubuntu starts?

Tags: wireless, drivers, lenovo, automation

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed on a Lenovo G50-30. When I installed Ubuntu I got some troubles with the WiFi. I couldn't turn it on/off.

I searched on Internet and found out some commands to fix it and it worked. But, every time Ubuntu starts I have to type this command to get WiFi up:

```
sudo modprobe -r ideapad-laptop
```

What can I do to fix this?

Also how do I run commands automatically every time the system boots?

Comment: You must have forgot to blacklist a module, see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the wifi is on and working then run the following command to blacklist the module.

```
echo "blacklist ideapad-laptop" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Reboot.

Answer (score 1):

`modprobe -r` is used to remove a kernel module. You can blacklist the module so that you donot have to remove it after every boot. For this open a terminal and type:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

By the above command  we are asking nano, the Ubuntu GUI text editor to open `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`. But normal users do not have permission to write to this file. So we use `sudo` to run the command with root privileges.

Add the name of the module you want to blacklist to the file opened using the following format:

```
blacklist driver-name
```

To exit, press `Ctrl + X` followed by `y` (for Yes).

Since you asked, when using Linux, you never have to type in the same commands everytime the system boots. You can automate it. If you want a particular command to be executed every time Ubuntu boots, just add this to `/etc/rc.local`. For this, open a Terminal and type, :

```
sudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

Once gedit is opened, write the command you want to execute during bootup starting from the second last line, ie. before `exit 0`. Save and exit.

Comment: your answer is not totally correct?

Comment: @WildMan, please tell me why, so that I can remove any mistakes.

Comment: You say "By the above command we are asking gedit, the Ubuntu GUI text editor to open '/etc/rc.local' but it opens this file '/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf' and there is always a possibleily that sudo being run with gui could allow root to take ownership of the files.

Comment: @WildMan Thanks! now I realize why gksudo needs to be used. usually use nano.

Answer (score 1):

Pilot6 has a PPA that will fix the problem without blacklisting ideapad-laptop

First we need to add the PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/ideapad-laptop
```

Then we can install it with

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ideapad-laptop-dkms
```

Then reboot

The only possible problem is if you have a broadcom wifi card that uses bcmwl because this will update your kernel to the 3.16 series and you would need the utopic version of the bcmwl-kernel-source that is [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/bcmwl-kernel-source)

Comment: This will not upgrade kernel. You mixed it with another ppa. But I did not tested it with 3.13, that's true.

Comment: Thanks so much, your answer were so helpful and it worked! :)

Comment: If it worked, then you can accept the answer and hope that the answer helps others with some of the Lenovo G50-30, G40-30, and G50-70 models that are hard blocked.  If other models are found, Pilot6 can update his PPA with the info.  Please consider filing a [bug report](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) so that this info can be put into the kernel

Answer (score 0):

If you have to dump ideapad-laptop module to unblock rfkill, I'd say very likely you are suffering from the [no_hw_rfkill](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/ce363c2bcb2303e7fad3a79398db739c6995141b) issue.

Threfore, I'd recommend asking on [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Drivers&component=Platform_x86) or [ibm-acpi-devel](https://sourceforge.net/p/ibm-acpi/mailman/) for further assistance, if you want to get that handled - once and for all.

If you also provided `dmidecode` output then, I think you should already be half done.